# PHP WSO2's WSF/PHP

Tags: php, soap, web-services, wsh, wso2

I am trying to use WSO2' WSF for PHP and I am using a WS Security object.  I am making the request to the server and getting an Authentication error.  I believe the WS Security Object is missing something, so I would like to see the RAW SOAP message being sent...Is there a way to do this.

I am not doing this locally.

Comment: "I would like to see the RAW SOAP"  Don't bury the lead.  Work that into the title of the question.  It would also be a good idea to post the error message, in case someone has some experience with it that may be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.  Construct your SOAP client like so:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('location' => $endpoint_url, 'trace' => true));
```

Then, after you've sent your message, just call `$client->__getLastRequest()` or `$client->__getLastResponse()` as appropriate.  You can also call `$client->__getLastRequestHeaders()` or `$client->__getLastResponseHeaders()`.

Note that it is not possible to get any of this *before* sending the message.  You must first send the SOAP message.

Also, you may find http://us.php.net/soapclient helpful.

Comment: I am not using the default PHP soap client I am using WSO2's, but that got me looking to see if it had a similar method. so $client->getLastRequest() is what i was looking for thanks!